# (Python3) Is it better to access a dictionary many times, or to have a reference of the value of the item?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, reference

So for instance:

```py
if(self._ConnectGenes[innov_num].is_enabled() and self._ConnectGenes[innov_num].is_computed()==False):
     self._NodeGenes[self._ConnectGenes[innov_num]._Out].value += self._NodeGenes[next] * self._ConnectGenes[innov_num]._Weight
     self._ConnectGenes[innov_num].set_computed(True)
     queue.append(self._ConnectGenes[innov_num]._Out) #Append the next skirt to the graph
```

We have here some accesses of the dictionary self._ConnectGenes and the item is stored at the key
self._ConnectGenes[innov_num]

I'm wondering, would it be better if we had a reference to that item instead, so for instance

```py
genome = self._ConnectGenes[innov_num]
if(genome.is_enabled() and genome.is_computed()==False):
     self._NodeGenes[genome._Out].value += self._NodeGenes[next] * genome._Weight
     genome.set_computed(True)
     queue.append(genome._Out) #Append the next skirt to the graph
```

Would that save some performance?
Since this piece of code will be called many times.

Solution:

an experiment:

```py
import time

#----Preparation
access_dict = {"num":4}

#----Timing
start = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    access_dict["num"] = access_dict["num"] +1
end = time.time()
print("Dict access",end - start)

#----Timing
start = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    access_dict["num"] +=1
end = time.time()
print("Dict access2",end - start)

#----Timing
start = time.time()
ref = access_dict["num"]
for i in range(100000000):
    ref = ref +1
end = time.time()
print("Ref access",end - start)


#----Timing
start = time.time()
ref = access_dict["num"]
for i in range(100000000):
    ref += 1
end = time.time()
print("Ref access2",end - start)
```

Output:

```sh
Dict access 7.079166889190674
Dict access2 6.49668288230896
Ref access 5.318424224853516
Ref access2 5.393644332885742
```

Comment: Readability counts far more than a slight performance improvement, and as such the refactored version would be preferable even if it were slightly *slower*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the dict, you incur hashing/lookup overhead every time. Looking up the same key repeatedly is a waste of cycles if you're going to use it multiple times in the same code block. Storing the result in a variable will be faster and cleaner.